# external maven repo and jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, repository

I have an external jar(meaning not available in a public repo), that i want o include in my build.
I used the instructions found on this site:
http://charlie.cu.cc/2012/06/how-add-external-libraries-maven/
and it works, when I do mvn install in my PC.
But when I am building the maven project using Jenkins, i get the following error:

> Executing Maven:  -B -f D:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\rmy
>   job\pom.xml install [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]
>
> ### [INFO]
>
> ### [INFO] Building xxxxxx 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
>
> [WARNING] The POM for sqljdbc:sqljdbc_4.0:jar:v4 is missing, no
>   dependency information available
>
> ### [INFO]
>
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total
>
> time: 1.705s [INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 11 10:29:23 EET
>   2014
>
> [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/307M
>   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xxxxxx: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.xx:xxxxxxx:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to
>   find sqljdbc:sqljdbc_4.0:jar:v4 in
>   http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of codehaus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

The pom that i am using has these entries for repositories:

```
    <repositories>
<repository>
    <id>codehaus</id>
    <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus</url>
</repository>

<!-- In Project repository -->
<repository>
    <id>in-project</id>
    <name>In Project Repo</name>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url>
</repository>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tries, i did the following workaround in pom.xml

```
<repository>
    <id>in-project</id>
    <name>In Project Repo</name>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url>
</repository>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>sqljdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc_4.0</artifactId>
    <version>v4</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/sqljdbc/sqljdbc_4.0/v4/sqljdbc_4.0-v4.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

This means that the system path is needed as a whole and not just

```
 <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
```

as it was mentioned above.
By this "workaround" I got it to work both locally and remotely (Jenkins-Git)

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule I always strongly recommend to

- use a Maven Repository Manager such as Nexus
- only manage repositories in the Maven Repository Manager, not  in the POMs
- use the Maven Repository Manager to host third-party libraries not available from any other repository
- [configure your settings file](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html)

This is a key to get stable and reproducible builds - even when one of the repositories is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Puce. This is something that i will definitely, when i have the resources..However, I currently have the above implementation, and i need to solve this

Comment: It's better to go the suggested way, cause it will cost you more effort to solve your current issues and which will follow them behind.

Answer (score 1):

Actually that might be hppen that it can't get the jar from lib.

tyr it with other way.

1. right click project
2. select property
3. java build path
4. select Lib
5. add external jar and put set path of your jar files
6. finish
7. clean and build your project.

### **OR**

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
        <id>local123</id>
        <name>localRepo</name>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
     </repositories>
```

try putting this code in **pom.xml** file.

hope your problem can be resolve using this.

Comment: I cannot do the first option, because Jenkins takes the src from Git.So even if i include the jar locally, when jenkins pulls the code form git, there will be a problem. Regarding your second option, this is what I currently do.Only id and name is different, and as i said it didn't work